# Linux command called "file" returns "application/x-empty" only when executing through web

Tags: ajax, linux, perl, file, mime

I'm trying to execute the command "file /directory/*" through the web, using Ajax that call a perl script.

When I'm running the script from the server I get the mime type correctly, but when i'm using the web that trigger the ajax, i'm getting "application/x-empty".

If i'm running the command from the server using "sudo -u apache perl_script.pl" - the result is correct.

Why from the Ajax I get a different response ?

Comment: Is the `file` program you are trying to call one that you wrote? Or are you trying to call the standard `file` program?

Comment: The code is simple, just: my $a = \`file /direcotry/*\`;

Comment: not another file permission problem?

Comment: as I said "sudo -u apache perl_script.pl" works. unless I forgot some flags in order for it be the exact emulation ?

Answer (score 0):

Try without the asterisk but instead with a complete filename.

Comment: Still the same, although i've duplicated the file that i'm trying to check (a.html, b.html), now the first one returns "empty" and the second one is ok. why ?

Comment: Actually, now i have 10 files, all of there are with mime "empty" and only the last one holds the correct mime type. what's is this thing ?